# Mongoose - findByIdAndUpdate and req.body deleting key values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a model with a lot of key/values, and a PUT route to update the model. I want to be able to send the `req.body` into the mongoose method `findByIdAndUpdate`.

For example, here is part of the model.

```
"generalInfo": {
    "tailNum": 1231231231231,
    "model": "sd9ia0da",
    "maxGasFuel": 1286123,
    "wingSurfaceArea": 123,
    "thrust": 123123,
    "takeOffSpeed": 123,
    "coeficientOfLift": 12334
}
```

When I send the request to update the `tailNum` value, it erases everything else in the `generalInfo` object and only leaves the `tailNum` key/value.

Here is my code for the PUT request.

```
// * @route   PUT /api/aircraft/:id
// ? @desc    Update an aircraft by ID
// ! @access  Private
router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dbAircraft = await Aircraft.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      req.body,
      { new: true, runValidators: true }
    );

    res.json(dbAircraft);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(`Server error`);
  }
});
```

I know I could de-structure the values of `req.body` and send them in a custom object, manually, but this model has too many values for that to be viable.

Comment: can you also mention code for Mongoose schema also?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. How did you verify that the data is erased?

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi absolutely. Here is a pastebin for the model. https://pastebin.com/3sxt5Nvy

@KashinathPatekar I verified with mLab by looking directly into the documents. 

Unfortunately, none of the solutions below (`$set`, spread operator) have worked.

Comment: I checked your Schema...I couldn't find any problems within that...Can you please mention your validate file also??

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi the file just returns true, it actually isn't written yet. So there shouldn't be any issues there.

Comment: What is the out put if we ran the update with setting false to `runValidators`? `{ new: true, runValidators: false} `

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi same output unfortunately. Could it be a version issue with Mongoose? I don't know. Here is the repo: https://github.com/graysonlee123/kelby-manifest

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue..Your code work just fine for me...I am using mongoDB 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to send req.body as an object like this:

```js
router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let update = req.body;
    const dbAircraft = await Aircraft.findByIdAndUpdate(
      {req.params.id,
       update,
      { new: true, runValidators: true }
    );

    res.json(dbAircraft);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(`Server error`);
  }
});

//OR
router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dbAircraft = await Aircraft.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {req.body},
      { new: true, runValidators: true }
    );

    res.json(dbAircraft);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(`Server error`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems incorrect. Use

```
router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dbAircraft = await Aircraft.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {$set: req.body},
      { new: true, runValidators: true }
    );

    res.json(dbAircraft);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(`Server error`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be much more helpful if you were explaining your solutions instead of just pasting some code. Giving more context not only helps the user that asked the question, but also everyone arriving here afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dbAircraft = await Aircraft.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,                     // «Object|Number|String» value of _id to query by
      { ...req.body },                   // «Object»
      { new: true, runValidators: true } // «Object» optional see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions
    );
  // Example: Model.findByIdAndUpdate(123456, { name: 'my name' }, { new: true, runValidators: true })
  // Example: Model.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: 123456 }, { name: 'my name' }, { new: true, runValidators: true })

    res.json(dbAircraft);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(`Server error`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be much more helpful if you were explaining your solutions instead of just pasting some code. Giving more context not only helps the user that asked the question, but also everyone arriving here afterwards.

Comment: @AlvinSartor Thanks for your suggestion. Should I add descriptive material for this matter ?

Comment: Some explanation of what your solution is trying to achieve or why you would go this way is going to be enough.